# need help - teradata TPT script failing

Tags: teradata

**TPT SCRIPT:**

```
DEFINE JOB LD_CAN_IN_TRANSIT
DESCRIPTION 'Load canada retail in transit'
(
DEFINE SCHEMA schema_Canada_Retail_Intransit_Wrk
(
VOUCHER_DATE VARCHAR(50),
VOU_NO       VARCHAR(50),
PO_NO        VARCHAR(50),
DOC_QTY      VARCHAR(50),
DESCRIP      VARCHAR(50),
UPC          VARCHAR(50),
STORE_ADDR6  VARCHAR(50),
COUNTRY      VARCHAR(50),
VENDOR_CODE  VARCHAR(50),
LINENUMBER   VARCHAR(50)
);

DEFINE OPERATOR DDL_OPERATOR
TYPE DDL
ATTRIBUTES
(
        VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'ddl_log',
        VARCHAR TdpId          = '******',
        VARCHAR LogonMech      = 'LDAP',
        VARCHAR UserName       = '*************',
        VARCHAR UserPassword   = '*************',
        VARCHAR ErrorList      = '3807'
);

DEFINE OPERATOR dml_canada_retail_int
TYPE UPDATE
SCHEMA *
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR LogonMech      = 'LDAP',
VARCHAR TdpId          = '*******',
VARCHAR UserName       = '************',
VARCHAR UserPassword   = '********',
VARCHAR TargetTable  = 'ODM_SCD_STG_T.abc' ,
VARCHAR LogTable = 'EIS_AUX_T.log_table',
VARCHAR ErrorTable1 = 'EIS_AUX_T.err_ET',
VARCHAR ErrorTable2 = 'EIS_AUX_T.err_RL'
VARCHAR DeleteTask     = 'Y'
);

DEFINE OPERATOR prod_can_ret_int
TYPE DATACONNECTOR PRODUCER
SCHEMA schema_Canada_Retail_Intransit_Wrk
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR  DirectoryPath= '<path_to_file>',
VARCHAR  FileName = @data_file,
VARCHAR  Format   = 'Delimited',
VARCHAR  OpenMode = 'Read',
VARCHAR  TextDelimiter =',',
INTEGER  SkipRows = 1
);

DEFINE OPERATOR load_can_ret_int
TYPE LOAD
SCHEMA *
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR LogonMech           = 'LDAP',
VARCHAR TdpId          = '********',
VARCHAR UserName       = '*****************',
VARCHAR UserPassword   = '***************',
VARCHAR TargetTable  = 'ODM_SCD_STG_T.abc' ,
VARCHAR LogTable = 'EIS_AUX_T.log_table',
VARCHAR ErrorTable1 = 'EIS_AUX_T.err_ET',
VARCHAR ErrorTable2 = 'EIS_AUX_T.err_RL'
);

STEP Setup_Tables
(
APPLY
('DROP TABLE EIS_AUX_T.log_table;'),
('DROP TABLE EIS_AUX_T.err_ET;'),
('DROP TABLE EIS_AUX_T.err_RL;')
TO OPERATOR (DDL_OPERATOR);
);


STEP stSetup_Tables
(
APPLY
('DELETE ODM_SCD_STG_T.abc;')
TO OPERATOR (dml_canada_retail_int);
);

STEP stLOAD_CAN_RET_INT
(
APPLY
('<insert statement>')
TO OPERATOR (load_can_ret_int)
SELECT * FROM OPERATOR(prod_can_ret_int);
);


);
```

**ERROR:**

```
Teradata Parallel Transporter Version 16.20.00.14 64-Bit
The global configuration file '/opt/teradata/client/16.20/tbuild/twbcfg.ini' is used.
   Log Directory: /opt/teradata/client/16.20/tbuild/logs
   Checkpoint Directory: /opt/teradata/client/16.20/tbuild/checkpoint

TPT_INFRA: TPT03624: Warning: tbuild -s option argument specifies the first job step;
  no job steps will be skipped (unless this is a restarted job).
Job log: /opt/teradata/client/16.20/tbuild/logs/ec2-user-207.out
Job id is ec2-user-207, running on ip-10-179-114-26.us-west-2.compute.internal
Teradata Parallel Transporter SQL DDL Operator Version 16.20.00.14
DDL_OPERATOR: private log specified: ddl_log
DDL_OPERATOR: connecting sessions
DDL_OPERATOR: sending SQL requests
DDL_OPERATOR: TPT10508: RDBMS error 3807: Object 'EIS_AUX_T.err_ET' does not exist.
DDL_OPERATOR: TPT18046: Error is ignored as requested in ErrorList
DDL_OPERATOR: TPT10508: RDBMS error 3807: Object 'EIS_AUX_T.err_RL' does not exist.
DDL_OPERATOR: TPT18046: Error is ignored as requested in ErrorList
DDL_OPERATOR: disconnecting sessions
DDL_OPERATOR: Total processor time used = '0.012241 Second(s)'
DDL_OPERATOR: Start : Thu Jan  9 20:22:28 2020
DDL_OPERATOR: End   : Thu Jan  9 20:22:28 2020
Job step Setup_Tables completed successfully
Teradata Parallel Transporter Update Operator Version 16.20.00.14
dml_canada_retail_int: private log not specified
dml_canada_retail_int: connecting sessions
dml_canada_retail_int: preparing target table(s)
**dml_canada_retail_int: TPT10508: RDBMS error 3524: The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database ODM_SCD_STG_T.**
dml_canada_retail_int: disconnecting sessions
dml_canada_retail_int: Performance metrics:
dml_canada_retail_int:     MB/sec in Acquisition phase: 0
dml_canada_retail_int:     Elapsed time from start to Acquisition phase:   2 second(s)
dml_canada_retail_int:     Elapsed time in Acquisition phase:   0 second
dml_canada_retail_int:     Elapsed time in Application phase:   0 second
dml_canada_retail_int:     Elapsed time from Application phase to end: < 1 second
dml_canada_retail_int: Total processor time used = '0.0397 Second(s)'
dml_canada_retail_int: Start : Thu Jan  9 20:22:28 2020
dml_canada_retail_int: End   : Thu Jan  9 20:22:30 2020
Job step stSetup_Tables terminated (status 12)
Job ec2-user terminated (status 12)
Job start: Thu Jan  9 20:22:28 2020
Job end:   Thu Jan  9 20:22:30 2020
```

---

**Question:**

The goal is to create error tables in EIS_AUX_T schema and
the user that i'm using have CREATE TABLE access to it.  But i'm not
sure why do i need CREATE TABLE access to database (ODM_SCD_STG_T in
this case) in which target table exists.  Process is failing at Load
operator step.

> 1.User have CREATE TABLE access in EIS_AUX_T database.
>
> 2.User does NOT have CREATE TABLE access in ODM_SCD_STG_T database.
>
> 3.USer has DML privileges in ODM_SCD_STG_T database.
>
> 4.Error and Log tables should be created in EIS_AUX_T database.

Comment: While it usually tell you in the TPT output you shared here, perhaps this is a restarted job where the initial run was trying to build Error tables or restart log tables in that database. Can you see if you have this job hanging out in `/opt/teradata/client/16.20/tbuild/checkpoint`? If so delete it and rerun your tpt. Other than that, your TPT looks like you explained and the [documentation suggests your permissions are correct](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/xEzC_kfDJe9nZZ6GRLPvHw/SiXScHR8F6C0FjtCPXSURA)

Comment: @JNevill Thanks. I have tried that but still error persists.

Comment: Should we have CREATE TABLE access in target database if we have a step to delete data in target table before loading?

Comment: You really shouldn't need it. If you check out that link in my comment it tells you the security required for each operator in a TPT script. For Target there is not a need for DDL access. I really don't know why it's being so picky.

Answer (score 1):

The UPDATE operator also uses a `WorkTable` in addition to Log & Error tables; since you didn't specify WorkTable or WorkingDatabase attributes, TPT is trying to create the work table in the target table's database.

But using the UPDATE operator DeleteTask to truncate a table is just extra overhead. Use the DDL operator for this.

Comment: i did exactly same and it worked. thanks for the input.